# Перенаправление на index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно прописать, чтобы при любом адресе открывался index.php. Т.е. я ввожу, к примеру, любой адрес любого содержания:

```
site.ru/index.php    
site.ru/index    
site.ru/abrakadabra    
site.ru/ololo/1/ololo/1    
site.ru/tralivali?brin=1    
site.ru/bregt.ru
```

и так далее... И в любом случае, чтобы я ни ввел, открывался index.php. Независимо, есть или нету такой папки или файла. Как-то вот так :). Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

RewriteCond - нужны, чтоб картинки и стили напрямую отдавались.

в скрипте в $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] будет нужная вам часть запроса